# Constructing an array of object with two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a nice way of transforming a flat javascript array into an array of objects?

An example would be to transform this array.

I'm stuck in trying to merge the two arrays and create an object with the values.

```
const dataSet = [
  {
    last_updated: 1662040601,
    x: [
      1660953600, 1661040000, 1661126400, 1661212800, 1661299200, 1661385600,
      1661472000, 1661558400, 1661644800, 1661731200, 1661817600, 1661904000,
    ],
    y: [
      0.07, 0.062, 0.06, 0.0725, 0.075, 0.089, 0.0799, 0.1167, 0.089, 0.08,
      0.077, 0.0639,
    ],
  },
];
```

Into this:

```
const array = [
  { data: 1660953600, value: 0.07 },
  { data: 1661040000, value: 0.062 },
  { data: 1661126400, value: 0.06 },
  { data: 1661212800, value: 0.0725 },
];
```

My attempt:

```
const arri = dataSet.map((data) => ({
  data: data.x.map((data) => data),
  value: data.y,
}));
```

Comment: Share your attempt pls :) A [mre] **always** helps you get answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will help you..

```
const array = dataSet[0].x.map((x, i) => ({ data: x, value: dataSet[0].y[i] }));
```

What do you think about it ?

Comment: consider adding runnable code snippets

Comment: Haha yes sorry @SalwaA.Soliman

Comment: // try this

const result = []

 dataSet.forEach(({x, y}) => {
  x.forEach((data, index) => result.push({data, value: y[index]}))
})